# I'm having trouble trying to splice an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hell:

I have been pulling my hair out over this.  I'm trying to splice a multidimensional array I want to delete the index that of row that has a 0 and then push zero to the end.  I'm able to push zero to the end but the 0 in index column 2 position 2 won't  delete.  I've tried every thing and thought I could ask for help to point me in the right direction.   I really need to get this' Here is my code and I appreciate any help.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var data = [
    ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['a', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['a', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
    ['a', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
    ['b', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['b', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['c', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
    ['d', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78],
    ['d', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['d', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['e', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
    ['e', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
    ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['e', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['e', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
    ['e', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78]
  ];

  //Create a HTML Table element.
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  var somedata = document.createElement("TD");

  //Get the count of columns.
  var columnCount = data[0].length;

  var count = 0;
  //Add the data rows.  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell.innerHTML = data[i][j];
      cell.innerHtml = myZero;
      var myZero = data[i][j]
      if (myZero === 0) {
        console.log(i, j, cell);
        console.log("is equal");
        console.log(data[myZero].splice(2, 1));
        data[myZero].push(0);
      }
    }
  }

  var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
  dvTable.innerHTML = "";
  dvTable.appendChild(table);

})();
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;  
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="dvTable"></div>
```

Thanking you in advance
PHD

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm!  I needed another set of eyes..                              Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes! I t worked like a charm.  I had changed things around so I guess needed another set of eyes.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You had some stuff out of order and your splice was referencing static values so i always spliced the third item in the array (position 2). you were also always pushing the `0` into the first array in the array of arrays (`data[myZero].push(0);`);

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';


  var data = [
    ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['a', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['a', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
    ['a', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
    ['b', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['b', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['c', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
    ['d', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78],
    ['d', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['d', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['e', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
    ['e', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
    ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['e', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['e', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
    ['e', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78]
  ];


  //Create a HTML Table element.
  var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  var somedata = document.createElement("TD");


  //Get the count of columns.
  var columnCount = data[0].length;

  var count = 0;
  //Add the data rows.  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
      var myZero = data[i][j]
      if (myZero === 0) {
        console.log(i, j, cell);
        console.log("is equal");
        console.log(data[i].splice(j, 1));
        data[i].push(0);
      }
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell.innerHTML = data[i][j];
      cell.innerHtml = myZero;
    }
  }

  var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
  dvTable.innerHTML = "";
  dvTable.appendChild(table);


})();
```

```html
<div id="dvTable"></div>
```